# React/Redux how to keep user logged with JWT

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, redux, jwt

im wondering what's best practice for keeping user logged in after closing the app. i created the application with a backend on MongoDB and express. On frontend user calls requests and some of them have JWT authorization token in header. It works well. How to check if the user is logged in immediately after loading the website. I want to use a LOGIN/LOGOUT button in header of the app and give logged users a premision to look at their profile. Should I create a "isUserLoggedIn" request function and call it in index.js immediately after ReactDOM.render()? Then backend will check JWT and send back e.g. user profile. Now i store Tokens in localStorage but i want to change it in future.

Comment: You could save the JWT to localStorage, and check it every time the app reloads. If it exists, user is logged in. If it doesn't exist, user isn't logged in. Although, then you have to take care of other things from a security point of view, like is the token still valid or is it expired, and what will happen if the request is made with an expired token, etc...

Comment: So, to do what you want you’ll first need to extend the shelf life of your JWT tokens, you could have it last a day or two but I wouldn’t push it past that. Then what you could do is create a JWT store it as a cookie on the server and have it sent to the client for authorization. If the JWT has expired they will need to login again if it hasn’t it will log them in and allow them to see the site and their profile.